# html canvas clearRect() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

Im study html canvas and trying to make simple animation.
I want to make rectangle move right. 
You can look at my code here.
http://codepen.io/inkluter/pen/GgeQqj

```
var x = 0, y = 0, w = 200, h = 100;

    function draw() {
       c.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

       x++;
       c.beginPath();
       c.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
       c.closePath();

       requestAnimationFrame(draw); 
    };
```

Problem is that clearRect() function  seems not working. Old rectangle still displaying on canvas.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'width' and 'height properties are defined in the canvas element, not the context. Write c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) instead.

Comment: Oh, what a stupid mistake. Thank you! i have spent 2 hours for this lol.